# @login_required not doing anything

Tags: django

It seems like @`login_required` decorator does nothing for me. If user is not logged in and calls registration, I expect it to redirect to login page. Am I missing anything. I even tried setting `@login_required(login_url='/login/')` but it didn't work out.

I have made sure to set `LOGIN_URL` and
`LOGIN_URL_REDIRECT`. All required parameters are there in `INSTALLED_APPS` and  middleware_classes. I am using latest django 1.9

```
def user_login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = LoginForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        print "u %s p:%s" % (username, password)
        user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
        print "Authentication done"
        if user is not None:
            print "logging in"
            login(request, user)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.POST['next'])
        else:
            print("The username and password were incorrect.")
    else:
        form = LoginForm()
    return render(request, 'login.html', {'loginForm': form})


@login_required
def registration(request):
    dosomething...

class LoginForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = User
```

Comment: Could you use the markdown to format the code in your post please?

Comment: are your `registeration` view and `LoginForm` class in the `user_login`'s scope?

**What is actually happening?**

Comment: Have you imported the login_required decorator?

Comment: Yes i have imported the login_required decorator and they are in user_login scope.

Comment: You may also just be logged in on your admin site. If you are, visit your site's admin (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin) and logout.  See https://djangogirls.gitbooks.io/django-girls-tutorial-extensions/content/authentication_authorization/

Answer (score 6):

It worked for me by clearning all browser cache. Thank you all for your support